# Why doesn't my completion block work?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

Implementing solution given here [How to make a synchronous request using Alamofire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961010/how-to-make-a-synchronous-request-using-alamofire?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I don't get any errors, it just doesn't work as expected. In tableViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData() { (didCompleteRequest) in
        if (didCompleteRequest) {
            self.TodosTableView.delegate = self
            self.TodosTableView.dataSource = self
            print("loading successfull")
        } else {
            print("loading failed")
        }
    }
    print("leaving viewDidLoad")
}

func loadData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(TodosViewController.serverAdress + "projects/index.json").responseJSON { response in
        do {
            // async stuff
        } catch {
            completion(false)
        }
        print("leaving loadData")
        completion(true)
    }
}
```

output I get

> leaving viewDidLoad
>
> leaving loadData
>
> loading successfull

apparently, the first element should be the last one

Comment: This is async request so it will not wait to finish your `loadData` so it is moving to   `leaving viewDidLoad`

Comment: Unrelated but you have to add a `return` statement in the `catch` clause to avoid calling the completion closure twice. The order of the output is correct as the closure in the `loadData()` method returns its data later asynchronously.

Comment: @vadian nope, I'll add, thanks.

Comment: @vadian Better yet, move the stuff (at least that 2nd `completion` call) that is after the do/catch block inside the `do` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `viewDidLoad` is running in the main thread. So when you put this `loadData()` in `viewDidLoad` controls dispatched to background thread where alamofire works on, and the main thread continues and prints **leaving viewDidLoad**

Try this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

  self.TodosTableView.delegate = self
  self.TodosTableView.dataSource = self

loadData() { (didCompleteRequest) in
    if (didCompleteRequest) {           
        self.TodosTableView.reloadData()
        print("loading successfull")
    } else {
        print("loading failed")
    }
}
print("leaving viewDidLoad")
}
```

Comment: thank you. just curious, why did initial solution work for others (in linked question), but not for me?

Comment: actually it works for you too , but you forgot to reload the table in completion

Answer (score -1):

You are call block code after get response from server. so first call "print("leaving viewDidLoad")".

response code get with delay so call block code with delay