# Alamofire synchronous request

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire-request, alamofire5

I'm trying to make a Log In Call to the backend using Alamofire 5. The problem is when I make the call I need a value to return to the Controller to validate the credentials.

So, the problem is Alamofire only make asynchronous calls so I need to make it synchronous. I saw a solution using semaphore but I don't know how implement it.

This is the solution that I found:

```
func syncRequest(_ url: String, method: Method) -> (Data?, Error?) {
    var data: Data?
    var error: Error?
    let url = URL(string: url)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = method.rawValue
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        data = $0
        error = $2
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    dataTask.resume()
    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)
    return (data, error)
}
```

And, this is my request code:

```
AF.request(request)
        .uploadProgress { progress in
            
        }
        .response(responseSerializer: serializer) { response in
            if response.error == nil {
                if response.data != nil {
                    do {
                        try decoder.decode(LogInSuccessful.self, from: response.data!)
                        
                    } catch {
                        do {
                            try decoder.decode(LogInError.self, from: response.data!)
                            
                        } catch {
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                statusCode = response.response!.statusCode
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a synchronous request using Alamofire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961010/how-to-make-a-synchronous-request-using-alamofire)

Comment: "the call I need a value to return to the Controller to validate the credentials" Why exactly? Usually it's a bad idea. Could you clarify why you can't manage asynchrone?